# Help to find the International Trauma Questionnaire (ITQ)

Tags: measurement, personality

I'm looking for the *International Trauma Questionnaire (ITQ)* as per ICD-11 proposals, but I can not find it. It was previously called *the
ICD-11 Trauma Questionnaire (ICD-TQ)*. Can someone help me?

Comment: Since it's a proposal, it might not be publicly available. There are some papers about it. One cites it as "Cloitre, M., Roberts, N.P., Bisson, J. I., & Brewin, C. R. (under development). The
ICD-11 Trauma Questionnaire (ICD-TQ). Unpublished Measure."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the ITQ at the following site that we've made for the scale:

https://www.traumameasuresglobal.com/

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  Who are the "we" you mentioned when saying *"the following site that we've made for the scale:"*?

Comment: Also, the site title is *Internationally Valid Measure**s***" [plural] yet only 1 measure is provided. What about others?

Comment: Many thanks to Philip Hyland and Chris Rogers (@chris-rogers)!

Comment: @ChrisRogers: Philip Hyland is one of the authors of the paper you've cited in your own answer. That should make "we" obvious.

Comment: @Fizz, ChrisRogers is simply making points about what makes for a good answer on this site. This post is a little sparse...

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest going to the source which is [Cloitre, et al. (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1111/acps.12956)

> The ITQ is a brief, simply worded measure of the core features of PTSD and CPTSD. It is consistent with the organizing principles of the ICD‐11 to maximize clinical utility and international applicability through a focus on a limited but central set of symptoms. The measure is freely available and can be found in the body of this paper.

### References

Cloitre, M., Shevlin, M., Brewin, C. R., Bisson, J. I., Roberts, N. P., Maercker, A., ... & Hyland, P. (2018). The International Trauma Questionnaire: development of a self‐report measure of ICD‐11 PTSD and complex PTSD. *Acta Psychiatrica Scandinavica.* (In Press: September 2018) doi: [10.1111/acps.12956](https://doi.org/10.1111/acps.12956)